# pyspark dataframe get partitions keys

Tags: pyspark

What's the simplest/fastest way to get the partition keys? Ideally into a python list.

Ultimately want to use is this to not process data from partitions that have already been processed. So in the example below only want to process data from day 3. But there may be more than 1 day to process.

Lets say the directory structure is

```
date_str=2010-01-01
date_str=2010-01-02
date_str=2010-01-03
```

Reading the dataframe with partition information

```
ddf2 = spark.read.csv("data/bydate")
```

Solutions I have tried below. They look excessively wordy and not sure if they are fast. The query shouldn't read any data since it just needs to check directory keys.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

ddf2.select(F.collect_set('date_str').alias('date_str')).first()['date_str']
# seems to work well albeit wordy

ddf2.select("date_str").distinct().collect()
# [Row(date_str=datetime.date(2010, 1, 10)), Row(date_str=datetime.date(2010, 1, 7)),
# not a python list and slow?

ddf2.createOrReplaceTempView("intent")
spark.sql("""show partitions intent""").toPandas()
# error

ddf2.rdd.getNumPartitions()
# not returning the keys, just the number, which isn't even all the keys
```

[Convert distinct values in a Dataframe in Pyspark to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45556625/convert-distinct-values-in-a-dataframe-in-pyspark-to-a-list)

[PySpark + Cassandra: Getting distinct values of partition key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47159469/pyspark-cassandra-getting-distinct-values-of-partition-key)

[pyspark - getting Latest partition from Hive partitioned column logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55053218/pyspark-getting-latest-partition-from-hive-partitioned-column-logic)

[Show partitions on a pyspark RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29056079/show-partitions-on-a-pyspark-rdd)

Comment: how about a simple condition `ddf2.where(F.col('date_str') >= '2010-01-03')` ?

Comment: yes but i need to retrieve the `'2010-01-03'` somehow from the partition keys

Comment: on the actual data `ddf2.where(F.col('date_str') >= '2010-01-03').limit(10).show()` takes a few seconds while the `set` and `distinct` functions run for several minutes, seems it reads all data instead of just looking at the partition keys which it should be able to in a few seconds also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So indeed the `set` and `distinct` solutions scan all the data and will be horribly slow on large data. The details are documented here

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-34194

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12890

Afaik the fastest way to get partition keys is this solution [pyspark - getting Latest partition from Hive partitioned column logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55053218/pyspark-getting-latest-partition-from-hive-partitioned-column-logic/65724151#65724151)

Adopted to get into a list (one partition solution)

```
spark.catalog.createTable(
    'table',
    path='data/bydate',
    source='csv',
)
spark.catalog.recoverPartitions('table')

df_partitions = spark.sql('show partitions table').toPandas()
partitions = df_partitions['partition'].str.replace('dt=','').tolist()
```

Since there isn't a neat pyspark solution, can use the below on the directories.

Databricks: `ls` the directory

```
import re
[re.search('(\d+)', o.name).group() for o in dbutils.fs.ls(cfg_fpath_intent)]
```

S3: use [datawrangler list_directories](https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/2.10.0/stubs/awswrangler.s3.list_directories.html#awswrangler.s3.list_directories) instead of `ls`

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at each of your approaches

**Approach #1:**

> `ddf2.select(F.collect_set('date_str').alias('date_str')).first()['date_str']`

There is nothing wrong with this, except (as you said), it's unnecessarily long.

**Approach #2:**

> `ddf2.select("date_str").distinct().collect()`

I'd say this might be the best approach, but `collect` return a list of rows, you'd need to loop through it like this. (And it's not *that* slow compare with other solutions.)

```py
[r['date_str'] for r in ddf2.select("date_str").distinct().collect()]
```

**Approach #3:**

> `spark.sql("""show partitions intent""").toPandas()`

This won't work because you're reading from CSV files, not a table.

**Approach #4:**

> ddf2.rdd.getNumPartitions()

This won't work either. "partition" in `getNumPartitions` is not the same as "table partitioning". `getNumPartitions` is the [number of partitions in RDD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.getNumPartitions).